# Quoting and Practicing Sharia law?

Tags: discussion

I have seen people here quoting the sharia law as reference to their answers but the question is: Is sharia law to be referenced? Considering the fact that sharia law is man-made law and also it's not the same everywhere, almost every Muslim country has their own version of sharia law that they follow except I do know it originally was created in Saudi Arabia.

Also there are some Muslim countries that completely reject the Sharia law complaining that it contains violent ideas that cannot be practiced in the modern age. So the question is: Is the sharia law even relevant in today's time and also whether to quote it as a reference?

Comment: **"Sharia law is man made law..."** => (!!!) How?

Comment: One could say strictly speaking saying anything bad about shari'a law is saying Allah isn't wise and didn't make a good or practical law and this would take you out of the folds of Islam. As insulting shari'ah  (Allahs law for mankind) is insulting Allah.

Comment: "One could say strictly speaking saying anything bad about shari'a law is saying Allah isn't wise..." The thing is that most of the controversy around the sharia law are based on hadiths. Such as killing an stoning and the death penalty for those who abandon Islam... unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: I mean there is a reason why scholars have different point of views on how to handle Apostasy in Islam

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: While it's probably not the best possible reference, it's not inherently wrong; it's part of Islam.  Interpret carefully and vote according to usefulness and quality (like with all answers).  If possible, suggest a less-derivative reference to add; otherwise constructively highlight to the author and future readers the problem (future readers can vote according to how they see things).

---

I'd say it's definitely within the "rules" to use Sharia law (in the sense of official government laws).  While it's implementations vary from country to country (like many things in Islam), it's part of Islam, and derived from Islamic sources.  If applied to a population which has wide-reaching impact, it's probably derived from reliable fatawa.

The reader should weigh its usefulness for themself (like with every answer):

> It is important to judge the evidences provided by each answer to the best of your own abilities, and accept such answers at your own risk. -- [On topic page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

E.g. they can upvote or downvote according to usefulness, e.g., the quality and applicability of the reference to the question.

In the case it's unhelpful, perhaps comment with either the aim to prompt the author to improve the post, or [in the case that the author and commenter are in disagreement] to highlight to subsequent readers the issue, who can also vote according to how they see things.

Constructive comments, e.g., *The Sharia law reference seems to be derived from [this Qur'an ayah]; would it be okay to add this reference?* will tend to be better received.  And even if the author doesn't add the reference, it will help future readers.

---

There's very little in Islam that isn't "man made".  E.g. you can quote the Qur'an, but to understand it accurately requires hadith (man made), tafsir (man made), fatawa (man made), your own deductions (man made), and so on.

The actual problem with quoting Sharia law seems to be that it's derivative.  Sharia law is derived from fatawa, which is derived from Qur'an and hadith (and other fatawa, and maybe even [qiyas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qiyas) which are influenced by political pressure and personal prejudices).

Secondary sources, in this case Sharia law, can be used to support that a particular interpretation of the Qur'an and ahadith is reasonable.

Comment: I'm not sure I read this correctly, it sounds like you're saying raw quotes from Quran and ahadith are better references than fiqh discourse?

Comment: I'd say they're better together:  "This is an authority's conclusion, and this is how they came to that conclusion."  Sharia law seems to be another step down the line ("...therefore we implement ABC").

Comment: Though I do agree with some of your points but your saying that it is "not inherently wrong" is what I don't agree with. A lot of Muslims in Pakistan, Malaysia etc and also people like me are against the Sharia we do consider it as backward and oppressing because it manipulated the texts of Quran and Sunnah to fit their aims, also terrorists use the Sharia law to justify their acts, what do you think?

Comment: I'm saying it's not inherently wrong as a reference at Islam.SE.

Comment: Ok I get your point, thank you for you answer!

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get the answer whether is it applicable in the present times?

Comment: @JessGarnald It's not quite clear what questions you'd like an answer to and where they belong. "Is sharia-based national law an appropriate reference on islam.se to substantiate claims about Islam?" As this answer outlines, to a somewhat limited extent. "Is it Islamic doctrine to say sharia is binding on Muslims today?" Belongs on the main site, and the answer would almost certainly be "yes". "Does contain sharia immoral elements?" I'm not sure that belongs anywhere on islam.se since it would be evaluating Islam by non-Islamic principles. "Does Islam command X violent behavior?" -> main site

Comment: "Does sharia contain immoral elements" can be a question as it is man-made and therefore can be questioned. Now my question is not the same, my question is "Sharia still relevant in today's times?" which is a simple question

Comment: @JessGarnald: It looks this question was misinterpreted as being specifically about the Sharia law references on Islam.SE and migrated here.  Perhaps it's worth asking another question on the main site, highlighting a specific Islam-related question.  [Keeping in mind the concerns about subjective and argumentative questions.]

Comment: @JessGarnald "Sharia still relevant in today's times?" I agree with RebeccaJStones, that should go on the main site. You will have to specify what you mean by "relevant".